# Gyrator Derivation

Tags: gyrator

I am trying to understand the input impedance calculation of this Gyrator circuit from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrator).

[image]

The input impedance Zin is given as:

[image]

I am having trouble deriving this. My first reaction was to say Zin = Vin/Iin and setup a system of 4 equations to solve this. The math is not giving me an elegant answer like in the Wikipedia article. I am ending up with a far more complicated solution. Am I missing some easier approach to see the solution? It seems like the solution in the article the author right away sees that the Zin of the top branch is Rl + jwRlRC and the Zin of the bottom branch is (R+ 1/jwC). I don't see how he/she gets that tho.

[image]

Comment: The reason you are having problems is that the Wikipedia formula is wrong!  If you do the calculations, you will find that Zin = Rl!

Comment: After additional research, I determined that you neglected to mention that "R is made sufficiently high so that the effect of the (R + 1/jwC) is negligible", therefore Zin = Rl + jwRCRl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I approach this is to initially assume that the combined impedance of C and R is very high. Then I calculate the output voltage of the op-amp: -

$$V_{IN}\cdot\dfrac{sCR}{1+sCR}$$

Then I calculate the voltage across \$R_L\$: -

$$V_{IN}\cdot (1 - \dfrac{sCR}{1+sCR})$$
$$=\dfrac{V_{IN}}{1+sCR}$$

And, because: -
$$I_{IN} = \dfrac{V_{IN}}{R_L+sCRR_L}$$

$$Z_{IN}=\dfrac{V_{IN}}{I_{IN}}=R_L +sCRR_L$$

In other words an inductance of \$CRR_L\$ in series with resistance \$R_L\$.

Comment: The last two steps are not correct, because you are only calculating the current through R_L, NOT I_IN!

Comment: I believe that the word should be impedance, not inductance (last sentence).  Also, it should be R not Rl.

Comment: @Guill I think you need to rethink what you are saying.

Comment: Andy, instead of a directive, I would like you to refute/explain why you think the last two steps are correct.  Are you saying that the current through Rl is Iin?  There are no inductors in the circuit, how do you get inductance?

Comment: I went to the source and found out that this is an approximation to a "simulated inductor".  So the op-amp, capacitor, and resistor, simulate an inductor which is in series with Rl.  The part that I was in disagreement is being neglected.

Comment: At the top of my answer I said this: "*initially assume that the combined impedance of C and R is very high*". The implication of this is that if you want to consider them then there is an additional impedance in parallel with the one I derived but surely that is clear from the formula in the question? Which part is being neglected?

Comment: this is not a complete answer @Andyaka you have kinda just jumped to the final answer after "and because", can you justify the "because" please?

Comment: @AndrewDavis thought it was clear... \$I_{IN}\cdot R_L\$ = voltage across \$R_L\$ so apply that to the formula above the "and because" bit.